# Doble creation of braintree customer ID when create an account

Tags: reactjs, braintree

[image]

I'm working in a React project, so every time I sign up a new user, it's created 2 customer ID, it's supposed to create inly one per user.

This is my code:

```
      const ConfirmEmail = ({ handleItems, onSubmitUser }) => {
      let params = useParams();
      
      let isMounted = true;
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      
      useCallback(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, [isMounted]);
      
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))) return;
          const response = await UserService.confirmEmail(params.tokenEmail);
          if (response && response.data && !response.err) {
            const { user, accessToken } = response.data;
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
            if (isMounted) {
              handleItems();
              onSubmitUser(user);
            }
          }
          if (isMounted) setLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
          const { response } = err;
          if (response?.data?.data) toast.error(response.data.data);
        }
    
        // Unmounted
    
        return (isMounted = false);
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a mistake when writing the code in the question, and you actually have:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Rather than:

```
useCallback(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [])
```

As in the second option, the callback you define is never called.

I suspect you are only experiencing this issue in development, because React calls `useEffect` twice in development when using `React.StrinctMode` (quick way to verify, just remove `React.StrictMode`).

You can fix this using a [`ref`](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs) to make sure you only send one request:

```
const ConfirmEmail = ({
  handleItems,
  onSubmitUser,
}) => {
  const params = useParams();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const confirmEmail = useCallback(() => {        
    try {
      if (localStorage.getItem("user")) return;

      const response = await UserService.confirmEmail(params.tokenEmail);      

      if (response && response.data) {
        const { user, accessToken } = response.data;

        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);

        handleItems();
        onSubmitUser(user);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err.message || 'Something went wrong.');
    }

    setLoading(false);      
  }, [params, handleItems, onSubmitUser])

  const emailConfirmed = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (emailConfirmed.current) return;

    emailConfirmed.current = true;

    // This will only be called once when the component is mounted:
    confirmEmail();
  }, [confirmEmail]);
};
```